# Ruby reading Excel includes extra '[" "]' to the values, how can I remove them?

Tags: excel, ruby, rubymine

I have this very simple Ruby code

```
xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new($docs_dir + '/mytestsheet.xlsx')
xlsx.each do |str|
  send_keys_characters(str)
  step %[I wait for 2 sec]
end
end
```

but the output returns the values between [" "] .e.g. ["xxxxxx"]["aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"]["bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"]["cccccccccccccccc"]
**How can I strip the extra [" "] and leave only the values please?**

Comment: `xlsx.each` yields rows, not strings. You probably want to traverse each row too.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for the quick reply; and how can I get only the strings?

Comment: Add another iteration, `str.each do |item|`

Comment: `xlsx.each { |row| row.each { |str| ... }}` should work.

Comment: @SaraTibbetts, thanks, but the same result: ["xxxxxx"]["["bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"]["cccccccccccccccc"]aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"] 
Am I missing something?

Comment: don't know what you want to do, why didn't you select the sheet first and then select each row? is `["xxxxxx"]["aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"]["bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"]["cccccccccccccccc"]` of 4 rows in the excel file?

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, one approach I like is to **destructure** the block parameter.

This article provides a more expansive overview of destructuring in Ruby:
https://jsarbada.wordpress.com/2019/02/05/destructuring-with-ruby/

For your example:

You can use parentheses to tell the block that you are expecting an array as the parameter, and you'd like to use elements within that array, rather than the array itself:

```
irb(main):001:0> [ ['a'], ['b'], ['c'] ].each do |(char)|
irb(main):002:1*   puts char.inspect
irb(main):003:1> end
"a"
"b"
"c"
=> [["a"], ["b"], ["c"]]
```

Notice what is being printed.  Those are strings.  The destructuring syntax of `|(char)|` (instead of `|char|`) causes the variable `char` to be assigned the first element of the array, rather than be assigned the array itself.  I believe this is similar to what you want.

Your code is more like this, without destructuring (notice the lack of parens within `|char_in_arr|`):

```
irb(main):004:0> [ ['a'], ['b'], ['c'] ].each do |char_in_arr|
irb(main):005:1*   puts char_in_arr.inspect
irb(main):006:1> end
["a"]
["b"]
["c"]
=> [["a"], ["b"], ["c"]]
```

So I would recommend you try the following code, and see if it fits your purpose:

```
xlsx.each do |(str)|
  send_keys_characters(str)
  step %[I wait for 2 sec]
end
```